# Spring security hasRole() giving Error 403 - Access is denied

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to view a specific page that only the admin can view but I am getting an error every time I make the request. It appears to be with the hasRole() in my security-context file.

The error just says HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied when I make the request to see the admin jsp page

security-context.xml:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasAnyRole('admin')" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/login"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
    <security:logout logout-success-url="/loogedout" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createoffer" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/docreate" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offercreated" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/loggedout" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/newaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/createaccount" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/accountcreated" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/offers" access="permitAll" />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
</security:http>
```

My two tables in my database are a user(username, email, enabled, password) and authorities(username, authority).

Could anyone suggest what my error is or how to fix it?

Comment: can you post the detailed error message, without it can't help you much.

Comment: @JasonZ Apologies, I have edited the post with the error.

Comment: Are you logging in as `admin`?

Comment: @JasonZ Yeah logged in as admin and I'm allowed do all the other tasks.

Comment: @What is the `URL` are you trying to access? Is it `/admin`?

Comment: @JasonZ Yeah after logging in I go back to the home page (/) and then try /admin

Comment: Try change `<security:intercept-url>`  like this `<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasAnyRole('admin')" />`

Comment: @JasonZ No unfortunately it is still giving me the same error.

Answer (score 7):

by default spring added ROLE_ prefix so changing `hasAnyRole('admin')` to `hasAnyRole('ROLE_admin')` should fix the error, unless you have custom implementation.

Ref:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.html

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.html#setRolePrefix(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that when you login as admin, You really have the admin role. 
Please see the out put of following code:
 `getCurrentUser().getAuthorities();` 
in any of the flows that is permitted to all.
This will simply list all the roles your logged in user has.

```
public UserInfo getCurrentUser() {
        UserInfo userInfo = null;
        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (securityContext != null && null != securityContext.getAuthentication()) {
            Object principal = securityContext.getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
            if (UserInfo.class.isAssignableFrom(principal.getClass())) {
                userInfo = (UserInfo) principal;
            }
        }
        return userInfo;
    }
```