# I cannot access /admin page after I configured spring security role as hasRole('admin')

Tags: spring-security

I am learning spring security 4.0.3 and I set authenticated admin page as:
 in [security-contex.xml] page. my database are a user(username, email, enabled, password) and authorities(username, authority).
I can log into properly and do other activities except that I cannot access admin page?

Any one who knows the solution?

The idea is I am trying to authorize my admin.jsp page for someone who has administrator role only.I use xml configuration.
as follow:
I am facing the same error as error in the [Spring security hasRole() giving Error 403 - Access is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34928751/spring-security-hasrole-giving-error-403-access-is-denied?rq=1)
I am exactly having the same error with the same code in the link above.
[I am sorry i cannot copy my xml file as i new to stackOverflow it shows me code formatting error for my xml fiel.
I have tried all the proposed solutions under the above link but still same.error.

Comment: can you post more example code plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I have solved this problems as follows:

1. changing`<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('admin')" />`  to `<security:intercept-url pattern="/admin" access="hasRole('ROLE_admin')" />`
2. Updating(changing) my database  authorities table [authority] coloumn  [admin] value to [ROLE_admin]
3. Update  maven project
   ...... worked form.  Thank you all